# exclude iPad from iOS user.agent redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, user-agent, tablet

I have re-purposed a PHP mobile device detect script into JS, works fine but I would like to exclude a tablet user agent.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/opera mini/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/blackberry/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/(pre\/|palm os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine)/i)) ||
     (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iris|3g_t|windows ce|opera mobi|windows ce; smartphone;|windows ce; iemobile)/i)) /*|| (navigator.userAgent.match(/(mini 9.5|vx1000|lge |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless| mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320|vx10|nokia|sony cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|kindle|mobile|psp|treo)/i))*/)
{
   window.location.replace("http://mymobileoptimisedsite.com");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this script currently exclude iPad UA-strings already?

Comment: Please, please, please do feature detection rather than this kind of user agent matching. It is extremely fragile and not likely to get you what you want anyway. If I'm not misreading it, it currently mistakenly identifies Android and Blackberry tablets, and doesn't identify eg. Nokia phones, Firefox OS phones, and Windows 7/8 mobiles. Even if these don't have a large amount of marketshare where you are, the situation differs wildly globally, and is constantly in flux. If you must use UA detection, do it server-side with a regularly updated full database, like WURFL.

Comment: @hongaar - It would seem that way, but it redirects on iPad/2 (iPad 3 not tested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change the first line to:

```
if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||
```

Furthermore, I agree with @Gijs' comment. Try to detect i.e. screen dimensions and touch support to decide whether to redirect or not (or better yet, make a responsive layout!).